# Image Path not working through my Backend to Frontend

Tags: c#, html, .net, angular

I am trying to get photos from my back-end and display it on my website. 
Here as you can see my images are stored in my api and the path needs to be `localhost:44333/Images/[imagename]`

[image: My image path]

In the other hand i added my path dynamicly to my frontend as you can see below.

[image]

But my photo never showed up on my site.
[image]
And when i go the image url it looks fine as you can see below:
[image]
I tried too many different paths but it is not working. I tried normal paths from the internet or the asset file it works when i do that but i can not get my photos from my backend localhost to my front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out the problem. When i tried to use staticfiles in my api startup.cs my problem solved.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add **app.UseStaticFiles("/wwwroot");** method in program.cs file
[image]

Comment: I just find out but your solve looks better. Thank you so much

Comment: your way is not working when i add new images to my database. I tried different variations of your way but when i add "wwwroot" as a parameter and if i don't add app.UseDefaultFiles(); it is not working.

Comment: for me it is working without app.UseDefaultFiles(); can  you share your program file image and image url which you using this code

Comment: i did not change anything. Just added your app.UseStaticFiles("www/root"); to my program.cs everything is same as at the question. when i do that its not working but if i add app.UseDefaultFiles(); and delete the "www/root"  its working. Even when i add  "www/root" inside staticfiles its not working tho. I have to delete that.

Comment: you aded slash in wwwroot word, www/root ?

Comment: yes i added exactly what you said thats just a miss click on my comment

Comment: can you refresh cache beacuse i notice when i change something in path they not reflected directly without ctrl+shift+r command

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try this

```
<img src="{{ carDetail.imagePath.path }}">
```

Comment: it needs to start with my backend localhost when i do what you said it will be only image name. I tried it and not working for sure. and carDetail.imagePath has no .path